# Fluid background image on browser resize

Tags: jquery, css, image, background, fluid

I want to achieve the fluid background image effect that you can see in this webpage: 
http://217.116.9.130/test2.html (taken from zara.com)

If you resize your browser to the left the woman in the image goes left with your resizing.
I've taken the code from zara.com but I suspect the effect is done by a language I don't know.

Does anyone know and can give a clue (or hand me a link) on how to do it using jquery, css, ajax or php?

Thanks a lot

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are probably looking for this: http://css-tricks.com/perfect-full-page-background-image/

It's quite simple to implement so no additional comments needed.

Answer (score 3):

you can use css3 cover property. for it

```
.container{
        background: url(images/bg.jpg) no-repeat center center fixed;
        -webkit-background-size: cover;
        -moz-background-size: cover;
        -o-background-size: cover;
        background-size: cover;
}
```

**for check this link** 
http://css-tricks.com/perfect-full-page-background-image/

Answer (score 0):

do a css styling

```
background-position: center center;
```

other options are

```
center top
center bottom
left top
```

etc...

Answer (score 0):

There is just an onResize method used in Javascript so that when the browser changes then that changes the CSS for the background image's position.

Give the image an id: `id="fullImage"`

They then use javascript to manipulate the `left:;` css style.

As you resize `left` changes up and down.

This should do it:

```
var el = document.getElementById(fullImage),
width = window.innerWidth,
imageWidth = [width of image here];
window.onresize = function() {
  el.style.left = imageWidth - width + "px";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

For example, if your background image is contained in your body tag, then the CSS should contain the background image assignment and then include:

```
top: 0;
bottom: 0;
left: 0;
right: 0;
```

This way - when the window resizes - the background immediately changes with it. Same principle for providing an overlay for a modal dialog.